How to merge several Excel files into one file with one worksheet in C# using Syncfusion.XlsIO
I loop source files, open the file and the only worksheet, get the source range as worksheet use range, setup subsequent destination range, and add it to destination workbook and save it.
After some files can't determine exactly the number when number of rows became high, I get exception

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

at line
IRange destinationRange = destinationWorksheet.Range[currentDestFirstRow,currentDestFirstCol, currentDestLastRow, currentDestLastCol];

with the following value
destination range=[1037502,1,1047586,6]

If I stop loop after some files everything goes well, and destination file is generated correctly.
Beware that range parameters are int I don't find any reason to be out of range.
Thanks for any suggestion
public Test()
{
    Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("my_key");
    destinationFile = outputDataPath + "__merged.xlsx";

    // get list of file to merge
    filesToMerge = Directory.GetFiles(this.inputDatapath, "*.xlsx");

    using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
    {
        IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
        application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;
        /* set destination  workbook and worksheet
         * initialize destination Range
         */ 
        IWorkbook destinationWorkbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);
        IWorksheet destinationWorksheet = destinationWorkbook.Worksheets[0];

        int currentDestFirstRow = 1;
        int currentDestFirstCol = 1;
        int currentDestLastRow = 1;
        int currentDestLastCol;

        string currentFile;

        for (int i = 0; i < filesToMerge.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            /* get used range from worksheet of each input file
             * and copy to destination*/
            currentFile = filesToMerge[i];

            FileStream currentStream = new FileStream(currentFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            IWorkbook currentWorkbook = application.Workbooks.Open(currentStream, ExcelOpenType.Automatic);
            IWorksheet currentWorksheet = currentWorkbook.Worksheets[0];
            IRange currentSourceRange = currentWorksheet.UsedRange;

            if (i == 0)
            {
                currentDestFirstRow = 1;
                currentDestFirstCol = 1;
                currentDestLastRow = currentSourceRange.LastRow;
                currentDestLastCol = currentSourceRange.LastColumn;
            }
            else
            {
                currentDestFirstRow = currentDestLastRow + 1;
                currentDestFirstCol = 1;
                currentDestLastRow = currentDestFirstRow + currentSourceRange.LastRow;
                currentDestLastCol = currentSourceRange.LastColumn;
            }

            IRange destinationRange = destinationWorksheet.Range[currentDestFirstRow, currentDestFirstCol, currentDestLastRow, currentDestLastCol];
            currentSourceRange.CopyTo(destinationRange);
            string line = (i.ToString()).PadLeft(3, '0')+Environment.NewLine;
            line += $"file={currentFile}" + Environment.NewLine;
            line += $"destination range=[{currentDestFirstRow},{currentDestFirstCol},{currentDestLastRow},{currentDestLastCol}]";
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        destinationWorkbook.SaveAs(stream);
        destinationWorkbook.Close();
        stream.Close();
        excelEngine.Dispose();
    }
}


How many rows and columns are in your Excel file?

@ellison
The set of files can be a few hundreds 100-500
Each file can go from 1 to about 10.000 rows
everything works fine as long as the number of total rows is less than 1.000000 can't  determine exctly the number
columns 6-10

Are you sure this part:
destination range=[1037502,1,1047586,6]

is correct? Specifically, the number 1047586 looks very suspicious to me - should this read 1048576?
I ask because 1048576 is 2^20, which is the maximum number of rows in a (modern) Excel worksheet. That is, row 1048576 is the last available row in any worksheet.
I suspect the ArgumentOutOfRangeException is because SyncFusion thinks you're targeting a row beyond the end of the worksheet (not, as you say, because of any int-related overflow).
You are using 1-based indexing for the Range object. Are you absolutely sure that's correct? I can see that Worksheets, for example, is zero-indexed, so I would expect row 1048576 to be indexed as .Range[..., 1048575] (not ...76).
If you're sure everything's correct then maybe this is a bug in SyncFusion, but be aware that attempting to write beyond row 1048576 should throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException because Excel doesn't support this.
(If this is a SyncFusion bug, you could possibly try an alternative .NET package such as EPPlus.)
